# iOS AVFoundation set exposure value, in EV units

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Hi I'm building a scanning IOS app (BarCode and QRCode). I have a silder to adjust the exposure value (to make image brighter or darker depend on light condition. I'm using this to set the exposure value manually

```
captureDevice.setExposureTargetBias(slider.value, completionHandler: nil)
```

But my question is what is the min and max value of `ExposureTargetBias` so that we can set `min` and `max` value for `slider` accordingly?

Is this an appropriate way to adjust the brightness of image or there are another? (iOS).

Comment: how can we set exposure manually?

Comment: how can we achieve brightness as the built in IOS camera?

Comment: You're not interested in using autoexposure or tap-to-expose?

Comment: HI i'm trying to find way to manually change the image brightness (live the native ios app camera)

Comment: Did you check out the [AVCam Manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html) same project from Apple. It has everything you need for

Answer (score 5):

You can use `captureDevice.minExposureTargetBias` and `captureDevice.maxExposureTargetBias` for the min and max values of your slider.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below property from `AVCaptureDeviceFormat` to get the min and max values for exposure duration.

Swift

```
var minExposureDuration: CMTime { get }
var maxExposureDuration: CMTime { get }
```

Objective C

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CMTime minExposureDuration;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CMTime maxExposureDuration;
```

Note that you can not simply set these values into your slider directly. You might need to set it as 0-1 as the slider range and do a non-linear mapping from the slider value to the actual device exposure duration.

Here is the sample code from Apple [AVCam Manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
    self.exposureDurationSlider.minimumValue = 0;
    self.exposureDurationSlider.maximumValue = 1;
    double exposureDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds( self.videoDevice.exposureDuration );
    double minExposureDurationSeconds = MAX( CMTimeGetSeconds( self.videoDevice.activeFormat.minExposureDuration ), kExposureMinimumDuration );
    double maxExposureDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds( self.videoDevice.activeFormat.maxExposureDuration );
    // Map from duration to non-linear UI range 0-1
    double p = ( exposureDurationSeconds - minExposureDurationSeconds ) / ( maxExposureDurationSeconds - minExposureDurationSeconds ); // Scale to 0-1
    self.exposureDurationSlider.value = pow( p, 1 / kExposureDurationPower ); // Apply inverse power
    self.exposureDurationSlider.enabled = ( self.videoDevice && self.videoDevice.exposureMode == AVCaptureExposureModeCustom );
```

You might want to check other properties like focus, white balance incase if you want to get a clear picture of QR code.